# What is the general idea of Nitsche's method in numerical analysis?

Tags: numerical-methods

I know that the Nitsche's method is a very attractive methods since it allows to take into account Dirichlet type boundary conditions or contact with friction boundary conditions in a weak way without the use of Lagrange multipliers. And its advantage, which is to tranform a Dirichlet boundary condition into weak terms similarly as a Neumann boundary condition, is paid by the fact that the implementation is model dependent.

However, it seems to be too general for me. Can you give me more specific idea of this method? A simple example is costly.

Comment: You may have more luck at [scicomp.se]